# Django: Change the DOM id at form field level

Tags: django, django-forms

I understand that, by default, Django auto-populates *id* for each form field upon rendering with the format `id_for_%s`. One can modify the format by providing the `auto_id` argument with a different format as its value to the Form constructor.

That's not exactly what I am looking for, however. What I want to accomplish is changing the id of just one of the many fields in my form. Also, the solution should not break the use of `form = MyForm(request.POST)`.

PS. MyForm is a model form, so each id is derived from its corresponding Model field.

Thanks for helping out.

Comment: Could you get away with using a class?  That sure is a lot easier and less error prone (just have to modify the widget).

Comment: @sdolan - I forgot to mention that this question was about model form. I am looking for solutions other than changing model field name.

Comment: You wouldn't have to.  It'd just be updating the field's widget when you construct the `ModelForm`.  If this would work, I'll post a full solution as an answer.

Comment: @sdolan - I have tried updating the field's widget in `__init__`, that breaks the logic `form = MyForm(request.POST)` upon posting user's inputs back to the server. Unless your solution is a different one.

Comment: I posted an answer about altering the class names. See if that'll work for your use case.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The forms framework appears to generate labels here:

```
def _id_for_label(self):
    """
    Wrapper around the field widget's `id_for_label` class method.
    Useful, for example, for focusing on this field regardless of whether
    it has a single widget or a MutiWidget.
    """
    widget = self.field.widget
    id_ = widget.attrs.get('id') or self.auto_id
    return widget.id_for_label(id_)
id_for_label = property(_id_for_label)
```

Which means you can just supply your field widget with an "id" key to set it to whatever you'd like.

```
foo = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'id': 'foobar'}))
```

Or override init and set the attrs after form initialization.

I don't see how this could break a form as django's forms framework isn't ever aware of HTML ids (that data is not passed to the server...)

Comment: Yuji - You're right. Changing _id_ doesn't break django's forms framework. I got the html attributes _name_ and _id_ mixed up. It's the _name_ attribute that Django relies on mapping a form back to an instance of the model. Thanks for the answer.